# How can I include a field from another table within a request to create a new row using mysql and sequelize?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, mysql2

I am working on a mysql2, sequelize, nodejs/exprees app.  I have a post request and want the response from my post request to look like this,

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Daniel",
    "last_name": "Craig",
    "street": "123 Main St.",
    "city": "123 Main St.",
    "state": "CA",
    "zipcode": "30012",
    "phone_number": "555-555-5555",
    "email": "swells123@yahoo.com",
    "rsvp": true,
    "user_id": 1,
    "food": "chicken"
}
```

Food is a seperate table with the just a primary key id and a field named food all of the other properties are coming from the Guest table.  The guest can only have one food.
This is how the Post request is setup,

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  Guest.create(
    {
      first_name: req.body.first_name,
      last_name: req.body.last_name,
      street: req.body.street,
      city: req.body.street,
      state: req.body.state,
      zipcode: req.body.zipcode,
      phone_number: req.body.phone_number,
      email: req.body.email,
      rsvp: req.body.rsvp,
      user_id: req.body.user_id,
    },
    {
      include: { model: Food },
    }
  )
    .then((dbGuestData) => res.json(dbGuestData))
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json(error);
    });
});
```

This is how I have the association setup

```
Food.belongsTo(Guest, {
  foreignKey: "guest_id"
});
```

My food model has a foreign key of guest_id that references the id of the guest.  When I make a post request putting this as the body,

```
{
      "first_name": "Daniel",
    "last_name": "Craig",
    "street": "123 Main St.",
    "city": "Smallville",
    "state": "CA",
    "zipcode": "30012",
    "phone_number": "555-555-5555",
    "email": "swells123@yahoo.com",
    "rsvp": true,
    "user_id": 1,
    "food_id": 1
}
```

I get this error: food is not associated to guest.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add a reverse association from `Guest` to `Food` because you make a query using `Guest` as a main model and `Food` as an associated model:

```js
Guest.hasOne(Food, {
  foreignKey: "guest_id"
});
```

Second you need to indicate `food` property in `create`:

```js
 Guest.create(
    {
      first_name: req.body.first_name,
      last_name: req.body.last_name,
      street: req.body.street,
      city: req.body.street,
      state: req.body.state,
      zipcode: req.body.zipcode,
      phone_number: req.body.phone_number,
      email: req.body.email,
      rsvp: req.body.rsvp,
      user_id: req.body.user_id,
      food: {
        food: req.body.food
      }
    },
    {
      include: { model: Food },
    }
  )
```

See [creating with associations](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/creating-with-associations.html)

Comment: Thank you Anatoly!  This does work.  But it creates a new food item.  I want the food table to just contain 3 different foods.  Is there a way to do this without actually adding to the food table?

Comment: In this case how do you plkan to find `food id` if you have only `food` field in a request body?

Comment: I got it working.  Removed the include and food property from the create and removed the guest_id in the food table.  Made a food_id in the guest table and used that in the create.